# tinymce.WPWindowManager is deprecated. How to use the default editor.windowManager instead in TinyMCE 4 and WordPress 3.9?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4, wordpress-3.9

I have a TinyMCE plugin that opens a popin using the following code:

```
editor.windowManager.open({
    id : 'popin-div-id',
    width : 500,
    height : "auto",
    wpDialog : true,
    title : 'Edit Options'
});
```

Ever since I updated to WordPress 3.9 (which embeds TinyMCE 4), I get the following error in the console:

```
tinymce.WPWindowManager is deprecated. Use the default editor.windowManager to open dialogs with inline HTML.
```

If I remove the "`wpDialog : true`" part from the code above, my popin doesn't appear anymore (no error).

What do I need to change to use the default windowManager in TinyMCE 4? I checked their website and I could not find documentation about opening a popin from a div, but only from an external HTML page, see:

- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorial:Migration_guide_from_3.x
- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_custom_dialogs
- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:class.tinymce.WindowManager

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.  The TinyMCE docs are unhelpful, ditto the WordPress docs.  I had to go pretty deep into the TinyMCE code to figure out how to get my simple custom popup working again.

**Answer**

Use the `html` key to define your html in the object you pass to `windowManager.open`. Below, I'm using jQuery to select some html that I've placed on the page by hooking into the WordPress `after_wp_tiny_mce` action.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    title: ed.getLang('mm_tiny_mce.element_attributes'),
    width : 300,
    height : 300,
    html :
        '<div id="mm-attrs-pop" class="mm-tinymce-popup" tabindex="-1">' +
            jQuery('#mm-attrs-pop-tpl').html() +
        '</div>',
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onclick: 'close'
        },
        {
            text: 'Set Attributes',
            onclick: function(){
                //some code here that modifies the selected node in TinyMCE
                tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The relevant TinyMCE code is in `classes/ui/Window.js`, in particular the `renderHTML` property. https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/master/js/tinymce/classes/ui/Window.js

Hope that helps.  Cheers, Chris

Comment: Thanks @Chris for your answer! There's really no way to pass the ID of the popin div to TinyMCE directly? I'm asking this because using `jQuery('#mm-attrs-pop-tpl').html()` seems like a performance hit, and also I have other IDs in my popin so will they be duplicated in the DOM? I also have custom events attached to elements displayed in my popin, will I need to re-instantiate them in the duplicated div?

Comment: I looked at the TinyMCE code again and it doesn't appear to me that there's anything in v4.x analogous to the `id` key that used to work with v3.x. I get your point about duplicating DOM ids -- i.e that you have other id'ed child elements within your template. The best way around this would be to turn your child element ids into classes: i.e. `$('#uniqueChild')` becomes `$('#popup .uniqueChild')`. An easier but less sturdy approach would be to pass the HTML as a JavaScript string in your TinyMCE code: `html: '<div id="#popup"><div id="#uniqueChild"></div></div>`

Comment: I've upvoted your answer but I'll wait until the end of the bounty before accepting it, perhaps someone can come with a better solution, otherwise you'll get the bounty, cheers! ;)

Comment: It looks like I got 50 -- 25 yesterday and 25 today. Not sure.  This is the first time I ever "won" anything.  Thanks, cheers,  Chris

Comment: No I think you got the first 25 from the 3 upvotes, and the other 25 from the bounty... what a scam